# Exchange Room mailbox location details using GraphClient

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to fetch room mailbox details from exchange using GraphClient. And I'm getting successful response from the following API

```
 var place = await graphClient.Places["roomaddress@microsoft.com"]
.Request()
.GetAsync();
```

But the below address details always shown as null in this response. What's the issue might be?
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: - Outside of Graphclient/sdk, have you tried repro the issue with MS Graph Explorer? Can you repro the same result?
- Is the exchange room mailbox is hybrid or Office 365?

Comment: Do you have any updates?

Comment: Hi @Dev, Sorry, I forgot to update, I found one thing, the above query won't return those pieces of information, If we need such details we need to set information using the set-place command. Once we set a location, city, etc.. using this command, it will reflect in the result of above query.

Comment: Yes, you can use the set-place Exchange Powershell cmdlet to set the values for your exchange online mailbox and update its metadata info (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-place?view=exchange-ps). Glad to hear that the above is working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use the set-place Exchange PowerShell cmdlet to set the values for your exchange online mailbox and update its metadata info. Here is the related [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-place?view=exchange-ps)
- Then, use Graph API SDK or MS Graph Explorer and make the API call, it returns the values.